# How to have multipl 'level 3' modifier using xkb

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm trying to improve my keyboard layout using `xkb` and it worked great using the default 4 levels (or should I say 2 levels? I don't really know the terms..

*And when I'm at opening a parenthesis, I found xkb very poorly documented (or I don't know how to search).. Some speak of levels, some of groups, some define levels as shift being the first, AltGr the second and others consider the base character being the first then increamenting each combination. I mean there are many inconsistencies..)*

Anyway, here is the default 4 "combinations" with the key <kbd>M</kbd> in some keyboards:

```
// Pressing   <M> <Shift+M> <AltGr+M> <Shift+AltGr+M>
key <AB07> { [ m ,    M    ,    mu   ,      mu       ] }; // m M µ µ
```

Is it possible to add into the mix others modifiers?

For example with one extra modifier for example the <kbd>R Ctrl</kbd> I can have 6 combinations:

```
// Pressing   <M> <Shift+M> <AltGr+M> <AltGr+Shift+M> <RCtrl+M> <RCtrl+Shift+M>
key <AB07> { [ m ,    M    ,    mu   ,    mu         , comma  , semicolon] };// m M µ µ , ;
```

Or even 8 combinations with all the three modifiers..
*And in fact it seems that there is already an 8 level mapping in some `symbol` files with the keyword `EIGHT_LEVEL`*

However I'm not looking to get 42 combinations for one key..

Rather I just want to avoid awkward combination for my fingers and for that I prefer to still have only limited combinations with "direct access", like so:

```
// Pressing   <M> <Shift+M> <AltGr+M>  <RCtrl+M>  <RWin>+M
key <AB07> { [ m ,    M    ,  comma  , semicolon ,    µ   ] }; // m M , ; µ
```

I would also want to map other characters or even moves *(arrows, home/end, page up/down)* with other unused modifiers (capslock, numlock)

How can I do this ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: 8-level mappings use 2 level-shifting keys: `ISO_Level3_Shift` and `ISO_Level5_Shift`.  various combinations with of these with Shift (aka level2-shift) give you access to all 8 symbols in the mapping.  see the various `lv5:` options in `man xkeyboard-config`.  you may also be interested in this question and the solution presented: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302163/how-to-make-a-iso-level4-shift-and-lock-in-xkb

Comment: Thanks.. Do you know if it is possible to increase the levels? I mean I only intersted to combination that don't chord a lot (ie. two kestrokes - the nth level modifier + the key)?

Comment: if you're asking how to add shift-keys for levels 4, 6, 7, and 8, the previous link touches on those.  (the answer demonstrates latch rather than shift, but a shift implementation would be similar.)  ... if you're asking about a level9 and higher, see this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411887/222377

Comment: Thanks. So if I wanted to have only the `<levelX>+key` combinations (without chording), I should define the level 3, level 5, level 9, level 17, level 33 and so on *(level 2ⁿ+1)*? Is this even possible? If so (it'll weird though) I probably should put `NoSymbol` to all unwanted chording combinations?

Comment: as pointed out in the second link, level9 is not a current possibility without rewriting some code.  if you want shift/lock/latch keys for level4, level6, level7, and level8 (so you can reach those levels with one shift/lock/latch instead of 2-3, which i assume is what "without chording" is trying to achieve), the first link is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your support.. When you say *"without rewriting some code"*, you mean what kind of code? Also I'm really sorry about my bad english, but what I mean *without* chording is to have access to some symbols with only two keystrokes, like the regular shift. Just like the last example in my question above.. Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: to clarify, unless you are willing and able to revise X's XKB extension and support libraries like libxkbcommon, you should consider level9 to be *"not possible"*.

Comment: This is an old discussion, but just in case someone reads these comments now: One can certainly use many more than 8 levels in XKB. See this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272360/multiple-modifier-layers-with-xkb-on-a-japanese-keyboard?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

There you can use `group` to achieve the "two keystrokes" objective :

```
key <AB07> { 
type[group1]= "FOUR_LEVEL",
type[group2]= "TWO_LEVEL_BIS",
symbols[group1]= [ m ,    M    ,  comma  , NoSymbol],
symbols[group2]= [ semicolon ,    µ ] 
};
```

Now you must define the `type` `TWO_LEVEL_BIS` for using your desired modifiers.

It is worth to know than <kbd>Mode_switch</kbd> is a key that increment the actual group, so have a look to it's definition.